# unable to make call to service on GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

i am testing a sample web application on GWT , i have downloaded all SDK, and plugin on eclipse, i have designed a 
small forms which takes few inputs from user and when user click on button it is making call to service using RPC , 
now its giving error "

```
 **errorcom.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><pre>NOT_FOUND</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.SignUp/SignUpservlet</p><p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a>**
```

".
i.e it is not connecting to service at all, i am really stuck here kindly help me out to identify the bug.
i am sharing the codes below

this is the signup.gwt.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='foofysignup'>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
    <entry-point class="com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.client.SignUp"/>

    <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fsignup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.server.SignupServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fsignup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foofysignup/SignUpservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>SignUp.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

service file interface :

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
import com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.shared.SignUpFields;
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("SignUpservlet")
public interface SignupService extends RemoteService {
    public String StoreSignUp(SignUpFields obj) throws IllegalArgumentException;

}
```

signup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <!--                                                               -->
        <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
        <!--                                                               -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SignUp.css">

        <!--                                           -->
        <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
        <!--                                           -->
        <title>Wrapper HTML for SignUp</title>

        <!--                                           -->
        <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
        <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
        <!-- be added before this line.                -->
        <!--                                           -->
        <script language="javascript" src="/com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.SignUp.nocache.js"></script>

    </head>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
    <!-- we leave the body empty because we want   -->
    <!-- to create a completely dynamic ui         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <body>

        <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
        <iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
    <div id="signupdiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("SignUpservlet")
```

with

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("../foofysignup/SignUpservlet")
```

the rpc request should work. This is not a good solutions but it works at least.

As Terrell pointed out you app is loading from `/com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.SignUp/` but due to your rename-to attribute your app should be loaded from `/foofysignup/`. This may be caused by old files in you WebContent folder.

Could you post your SignUp.html?

Comment: thanks peter , i have replaced code its working fine, but basically we should not provide absolute path right

Comment: I would have expect `src="foofysignup/com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.SignUp.nocache.js"` instead of `src="/com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.SignUp.nocache.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a GWT Compile since adding `<module rename-to='foofysignup'>` to your gwt.xml?

From this error it appears that your app expects the servlets to be mapped under the default fully qualified module name : `RequestURI=/com.mpigeon.foofy.signup.SignUp/SignUpservlet`

Comment: Hi thanks for suggestion , i tried on compiling project , its giving same error